# vue-cli created website with official pwa plugin doesn't work in offline mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I was hoping the official vue-cli plugin would work in offline mode right out of the box but I can’t get it to work.

Steps taken:

I created a project using @vue/cli@4.0.5 using the official pwa plugin

I’m testing this by running the project locally by first `npm run build` and then serving up the file using:
This chrome plugin
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Load the website successfully

In the Application tab of the Chrome developers tools, in the Service Workers section, I click on the Offline checkbox.

[image]

EDIT: This screenshot is a little out of date. I'm aware that chrome requires https unless its running on localhost. I can confirm that I am locally hosting my site at: http://localhost:8887/

Refresh the browser

Notice the errors in the console of the browser.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

[image]

Are my expectations of the vue-cli pwa plugin wrong? I was under the impression a default setup would just work.

Even stranger still... is after clearing the storage and refreshing the page. It works once (in online mode) But refreshing it again (in online mode) still produces errors!

[image]

Comment: Do you use `mode: 'history'` on your router.js file?

Comment: If yes, can you add this  `<base href="/" />`  on `<head>` section in `index.html` page and try again.

Comment: I tried removing history mode and adding the base href. It still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using another method for locally hosting my stuff worked correctly. In my case I had to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve